# Scroll to top when tapping the status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I got a view controller (lets call it `MainViewContoller`) that's present 3 different tables (one in a time), user  can tap a segment control to switch between those tables.

To present those 3 tables, `MainViewContoller` has 3 other view controllers (A, B and C), each has a `UITableView` as a subview and handle it's own data.
When a `MainViewContoller` is loaded, it initiate controllers A, B and C, and add their tableViews to it's view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewControllerA *vcA = [ViewControllerA alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:vcA.view];

    ViewControllerB *vcB = [ViewControllerB alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:vcB.view];

    ViewControllerC *vcC = [ViewControllerC alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:vcC.view];
}
```

So for example when user tap the segment control and choose A, the `MainViewContoller` hide tables B and C, and unhide table A.  Something like this:

```
if (userTapOnA) {
    self.viewControllerA.tableView.hidden = NO;
    self.viewControllerB.tableView.hidden = YES;
    self.viewControllerC.tableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

**The problem:**

When user tap the status bar I want that the current visible table will scroll to top.
This behavior is pretty basic and one gets it for free when using a regular view controller, but as you can see my view controller is not regular.
I suppose that by using other controllers view as `MainViewContoller` view I break the default behavior, so my `MainViewContoller` doesn't handle the status bar tap.

Someone got an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is directly from the UIScrollView header file:

> /* When the user taps the status bar, the scroll view beneath the
>   touch which is closest to the status bar will be scrolled to top, but
>   only if its `scrollsToTop` property is YES, its delegate does not
>   return NO from `shouldScrollViewScrollToTop`, and it is not already at
>   the top. On iPhone, we execute this gesture only if there's one
>   on-screen scroll view with `scrollsToTop` == YES. If more than one is
>   found, none will be scrolled. */
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL  scrollsToTop; // default is YES.

So in your case, set all scrollsToTop to NO, except the one you want to enable at that particular moment.

Comment: 10x, that was very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You should register your nested controllers as child controllers.

```
[self addChildViewController:vcA];
[self addChildViewController:vcB];
[self addChildViewController:vcC];
```

I'm not sure if this will help to solve your issue, but that's the right way to do it.